# The aria2.addTorrent method in aria2c's RPC interface ignores "dir" option

Tags: linux, vps, bittorrent, json-rpc, aria2

I am using aria2c as a daemon (the RPC interface) on a server, and when I use aria2.addTorrent method to add a torrent + a specific directory where the files have to be downloaded, aria2c downloads the file but not in the directory that I specified

This is how I am running the daemon:

```
aria2c --log="the.log" --disable-ipv6 \
--enable-rpc --rpc-listen-all --rpc-listen-port=7777 \
--seed-time=0 --bt-tracker-connect-timeout=30 --bt-tracker-timeout=10
```

And this is the data (as a JSON) that I am sending to the aria2c server locally:

```
{
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "id":user_id,
    "method":"aria2.addTorrent",
    "params":[mfile_base64,[{"dir":outdir_str}]],
}

# user_id = Some random username or id
# mfile_base64 = Base64 encoded contents of the metafile (the .torrent file)
# outdir_str = The directory were I want the file(s) to be downloaded
```

And again, the file is downloaded correctly but not in the directory that I want: It is being downloaded in my Current Working Directory

And in case someone asks, my read/write access is fine, the directory exists before the download even starts, it is a normal directory, it's not a mountpoint to another partition or any other resource over a network, etc... etc... etc...

**EDIT 1**

```
# I tried this:
{
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "id":user_id,
    "method":"aria2.addTorrent",
    "params":[mfile_base64,{"dir":outdir_str}],
}

# And the download does not even start, it throws an error, this is the JSON response:
{'id': 'user1', 'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'error': {'code': 1, 'message': 'The parameter at 1 has wrong type.'}}
```

Comment: The options should be a dictionary, not a list with a dictionary in it.

Comment: @AnonCoward that did not work, check EDIT1 for details. If what I tried is not what you meant to say, then post an answer with what you actually meant to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## FIXED IT

There was a missing element in the params list: the URIs list
In my case, I left it empty since i got nothing to put in there

```
{
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "id":user_id,
    "method":"aria2.addTorrent",
    "params":[mfile_base64,[],{"dir":outdir_str}],
}
```

And it works: the options dict is no longer ignored and therefore, the files are downloaded in the directory that I want